# How to write the "import scala.io.Source" , "import java.io" libraries in SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am compiling the Scala program using the SBT but It gives me following error for "import scala.io.Source" , "import java.io"

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala#scala.io.Source_2.11;latest.integration: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.java#java.io_2.11;latest.integration: not found
```

My SBT format is given below:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.0.1",
"org.scala" %% "scala.io.Source" % "latest.integration",
"org.java" %% "java.io" % "latest.integration"
)
```

Anybody can help that how i can specify the "import scala.io.Source" , "import java.io" in SBT.

Comment: `scala.io.Source` is a scala package not an SBT dependency. Remove it from sbt.  Same goes for `java.io`.

Comment: see also: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Getting-Started.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to make a distinction between library dependencies and package imports: library dependencies are managed through the build system (like sbt or maven or grails,...) and make complete libraries (like a logging API, HTTP implementation, ...) available to the system being built.

At the program level, `imports` are used to bring specific parts of libraries into the scope of the code being developed.

Given this `build.sbt`

```
name := "examplebuild"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
  "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.11" % "2.3.0"
)
```

We can develop a scala program that can use the configuration library from typesafe and the http library from scalaj

`Sample.scala`

```
package com.example

import scala.io.Source  // from the Scala standard library
import java.io._  // import all io package from the standard java library

import com.typesafe.ConfigFactory // from the typesafe config library
import scalaj.http._  // import all members of the scalaj.http package

class Sample {
   // code here
}
```